# Personalization Picker Error WCM 7.0

Tags: wcm

While creating a personalization component and creating a new rule in `IBM WCM`  I am getting the error message:

> The selected item was deleted or moved and cannot be displayed 
>   Could you please help me regarding this issue. I am using WCM 7.0

Comment: Hi, Infact this is not related to code. issue is I am trying to create a personalization compoenet in WCM and for creating a new rule I am clicking on New button for rules. In the pop up window the Personalization Picker portlet is getting displayed. I am getting the error message in the personalization picker portlet. I am unable to attach a screen shot as I am a new user.

Comment: Similar problem has been reported in the below link also but no answer for that. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/wcmforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=478881D27146FD9D85257D57001D8B94

Comment: Hi, I found out the solution for this issue. This is due to permission issue in Personalization Navigator portlet. For this navigate to Portal Home-> Application->Personalization->Business Rule-> Personalization Navigator Portlet. Clidk on Workspace which appears on the left side and Extra Actions on the top and provide editor or manager role to user user id.